# Magento Error Handling *and* PHP INI error_log configuration

Tags: php, configuration, error, log

I have a problem marrying Magentos Error Handling with my PHP configuration settings for [`error_log`](http://php.net/error_log) and [`log_errors`](http://php.net/log_errors) in ther server configuration.

I'm using both the application as well as the Magento PHP API like

```
require 'path/to/magento/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
...
```

which initializes the Magento application as well.

As you might know, this also registers the Magento PHP error handler so that Magento can introduce it's own logging system.

However from what I've noticed, it also *resets* the `php.ini` configuration settings for the standard PHP error log (and probably as well the error level depending on own settings and if Magento runs in Developer Mode or not). This behaviour is also suggested in context of [Large "error_log" file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32251/large-error-log-file) .

As there can't be much done about the error level, I'm not so much concerned about the level.

What I'm looking for is that the Magento system at least respects my `error_log` and `log_errors` setting because the error handler can't catch problems at the level of execution time (at least this seems to me, I'm missing some very grave error situations logged in the Magento `/var/log/` folder).

Is there any way to let Magento do what it does (Magento's own error handling) but also configure it to respect the PHP error log settings? At best with not editing core, so I ask.

I currently use Magento Version 1.5 but I assume this is the same for other versions, too.